# How to get points to draw chord(diameter) on circle

Tags: circles

Please consider the figure below:

[image]

I hope I am asking my Question in right forum.. I want to get set of paired points on circle using diameter. What I have is center point of circle and its diameter.

Consider black line in figure. Line is passing through center, as well as equal to diameter of circle. Red and green lines are same, only the difference is of points used/angle. Can anyone tell me a formula or solution to get random **paired** points on circle. I hope my Question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Draw the circle's circumference based on its diameter. Then, draw lines passing through the center of the circle which cuts the circle's circumference.

Comment: @YiyuanLee can u give me hint how to draw lines passing through center of circle?

Comment: If i am not misunderstanding your question, you already have the center of the circle. Simply put a straightedge (ruler) passing through this centre and draw a line through.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want points on a graph paper or something similar.
We know equation of a circle:

```
 x^2 + y^2 = r^2
```

assume a radius or use what ever radium you want (say r=2)

hence  x^2 + y^2=4
     assume any coordinate x or y
i will use x=0.
y^2=4
solving the equation we get y= +2 or- 2
There you have your pair now (0,2) and (0,-2).

go on selecting values in any range and generate the pairs.
You can make a program and do this also.